# Cannot convert type 'TEnum' to 'int'

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I'm trying to convert an enum to a List as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489453/how-can-i-convert-an-enumeration-into-a-listselectlistitem) example
e.g.

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem {
    Text = v.ToString(),
    Value = ((int)v).ToString()
}).ToList();
```

This work but I want to amend it to work with a generic enum

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList<TEnum>(TEnum value)
{

        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = v.ToString(),
            Value = ((int)v).ToString()
        }).ToList();
 }
```

However the above code doesn't compile and gives

> Cannot convert type 'TEnum' to 'int'

for the line

```
  Value = ((int)v).ToString()
```

1. How do I fix this above code.
2. Why is it giving a compile error with generic enum and not with a normal enum

---

Edit: I have tried the suggestions in the thread but I get a further error:

Here is my full code:

```
public static IHtmlContent EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TResult,TEnum>(
    this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
    TEnum enumValue,
    string optionLabel) 
{
    return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)GetEnumList(enumValue), optionLabel);
}

public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList<TEnum>(TEnum value) 
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(v).ToString()
    }).ToList();

}
```

but I get a runtime error

> ArgumentException: Type provided must be an Enum.
>
> Parameter name: enumType

on the line

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(v).ToString()
    }).ToList();
```

What do I need to fix in the code to not get the runtime error.

Comment: Are you trying to assing to the Value property the int represented by the enum?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170784/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-t-to-int

Comment: Cast the TEnum to enum first

Comment: Important is the `where ...` clause from Ivan's answer. Add it to your methods: `EnumDropDownListFor(...) where ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a value, just the enum type.  You can use something like this

*Generic*

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList<TEnum>()
    where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable
{
    return ((TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum))).Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = v.ToString("d", null)
    }).ToList();
}
```

*Non generic*

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList(Type enumType)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<IFormattable>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = v.ToString("d", null)
    }).ToList();
}
```

Both methods are not compile type safe. Generic, because of the lack of an enum connstraint. Non generic - well, it's similar to the `Enum` static methods which are not compile type safe anyway. Both methods will throw runtime exception if called with non enum type.

Comment: non-generic method is not compile-type safe, because *any* type can be passed to method, including non enum

Comment: @Ash Correct, but same for the generic one, due to the lack of an enum constraint. Both can throw runtime exception if not called with an enum type. Which is similar to `Enum` methods.

Comment: If I use the generic way As soon as I add that where clause of "where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable " my code won't compile
Error CS0453 The type 'Type' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method 'MyHelperClass.GetEnumList<TEnum>(TEnum)'

Comment: @ozdev You need to add the same constraint to the calling method - where `TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable` - this is the closest to the currently missing `enum` constraint. If it was there, both calling method and the generic method would have been constrained with `where TEnum : enum`.

Comment: I get that error message when I add the where clause it to both the calling method and the method being called

Comment: @ozdev So probably you have another generic method calling yours. The type constraints must be the same in all generic methods involved. That's why I provided the non generic version - you can use it from your `EnumDropDownListFor` (w/o putting constraints) like `GetEnumList(typeof(TEnum))`.

Answer (score 6):

You've told the compiler nothing about `TEnum`. As far as its concerned, it could be a string, a DateTime, a BankAccount, a Bullet or anything.

To get this to work, you can use `Enum.Parse` and `Convert.ToInt32`

UPD: Let me just format the code from comment and fix compilation errors for SO-copy-pasters :D

```
public static int GetEnumIntValue<T>(T value)
    where T : struct
{
    Type genericType = typeof(T);
    Debug.Assert(genericType.IsEnum);
    Enum enumValue = Enum.Parse(genericType, value.ToString()) as Enum;
    return Convert.ToInt32(enumValue);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example how to use the Enum.Parse in the code example

Comment: `public static int GetEnumIntValue<T>(T value)   where T : struct {    Type genericType = typeof(T);   Debug.Assert(genericType.IsEnum); Enum enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value.ToString()) as Enum;    return Convert.ToInt32(test); }`

A bit of google fu on your part should easily have found that.

Comment: Thanks @ColinGrealy! 
Let me just format your code and fix coimpilation errors for SO-copy-pasters :D (see edited answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList<TEnum>(TEnum value) where TEnum : IConvertible
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = v.ToInt32(null).ToString()
    }).ToList();
}
```

1. Complier know that you use Enum type after `.Cast<MyEnum>()`.
2. But after `.Cast<TEnum>()` compiler doesn't know about type which can be.

Comment: I tried the code but I get a further error of "Type provided must be an Enum"

Answer (score 1):

compiler complains because type parameter in generic method is not constrained

also method doesn't have to be generic

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetEnumList(Enum value)
{
    return Enum.GetValues(value.GetType())
            .Cast<Enum>()
            .Select(v => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = v.ToString(),
                            Value = Convert.ToInt32(v).ToString()
                        })
            .ToList();
}
```

here still can be a problem, if underlying type of enum was not `int`:

```
public enum LongEnum: ulong
{
    A = 0,
    B = 3000000000
}

// Run-time exception: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

Comment: That's true, but then you have to call it with a value, not just the type. I.e: `GetEnumList(Blah.Test)` vs `GetEnumList<Blah>()`. It works, but it might be confusing in that `Test` is not used at all.

Comment: @Rob, method in question takes 1 parameter. i didn't change this part. yes, indeed, a bit inconvenient, but there is no constraint for enums only

Comment: Of course - I wasn't attacking the answer, merely leaving a comment for future readers if they stumble upon it. There's really no clean way to do what OP whats, so each approach has its down sides.

Comment: For `ulong`, you can solve the problem with this: `Value = Convert.ChangeType(v, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType())).ToString()` :)

Comment: @Rob, thank you for valuable comments. i tested your suggestion and it works as expected

Comment: I tried the code but I get a further error of "Type provided must be an Enum"

Comment: @ozdev, i checked your edit and it seems that you are trying another suggestion than mine. i suggest to use non-generic method

Comment: If I changed both methods from TEnum to Enum it won't work cause I can't call @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.MyValue, MyEnum,"") as it will say "MyEnum is a type which isn't valid in the current context"

Comment: Yes but its on the create MVC view screen so if I change it from MyValue I get runtime error NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Isn't it weird to ask passing a value in order to get a list? Like `GetEnumList(MyEnum.A)`. Which will be same as `GetEnumList(MyEnum.B)' etc.

Comment: @ozdev, dropdown appeared when i have tried `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m=>m.MyValue, Model.MyValue, "")`

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me,
Extention method :

```
public static List<IdNameDto> ToIdNameList<TEnum>(this TEnum @enum) where TEnum : Enum
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>()
        .Select(x => new IdNameDto
        {
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(x),
            Name = x.ToString(),
        }).ToList();
}
```

dto :

```
public class IdNameDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: updated the answer, all it was doing is add space between words in enum value.