# How to pass the x in typeof(x) as a method parameter when x is not a variable but an enum type

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have the following enum

```
public enum StatusEnum
{
    Open= 1,
    SemiOpen = 2,
    Closed= 3
}
```

I pass it in my ASP.NET 5 view to my custom HTML Helper

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SwitchStatus, typeof (StatusEnum), "- Please select Item -")
```

which is a method that uses Generic enum as parameter

```
  public static IHtmlContent EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TResult, TEnum>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        TEnum enumValue,
        string optionLabel) 
    {
        // bunch of logic omitted as not relevant to error
        //calling another method passing the TEnum
        return null;
    }
```

which works.

However I need to pass the enum type between a number of methods as I need to treat it as an `TEnum` and not a Type which `typeof` will pass.

From the above I add a where clause to tell the method the TEnum is an enum.

```
  public static IHtmlContent EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TResult, TEnum>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        TEnum enumValue,
        string optionLabel) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
        // bunch of logic omitted as not relevant to error
        //calling another method passing the TEnum
        return null;
    }
```

However then I get a red line in my view under

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor
```

in Visual Studio

showing the error message

> Error  CS0453  The type 'Type' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method EnumDropDownListFor

Basically as I understand it I need to pass it a `TEnum` and not a `Type`

However if I remove the `typeof` from my line

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SwitchStatus, StatusEnum, "- Please select Item -")
```

I understandably get

> StatusEnum is a type which is not valid in the given context

What I basically want to do is do is call `typeof` inside the method like this

```
public static IHtmlContent EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TResult, TEnum>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
        TEnum enumValue,
        string optionLabel) where TEnum : struct, IConvertible, IFormattable
    {
       Type enumValue2 = typeof(StatusEnum);
        // bunch of logic omitted as not relevant to error
        //calling another method passing the TEnum
        return null;
    }
```

and for that I need the MVC View to look something like

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SwitchStatus, Before_typeof(StatusEnum), "- Please select Item -")
```

so I am allowed to pass it and do the `typeof` in the method.

Is this possible?

---

Take note:  I can get it working with the non generic version

i.e.

```
    public static IHtmlContent EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TResult>(
         this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
         Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression,
         Type enumValue,
         string optionLabel)
    {
        //logic
        return null;

    }
```

which works perfectly

I just wanted to know if the generic version is possible somehow

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in `typeof (StatusEnum)` as second parameter, the `TEnum` becomes a `Type`, which isn't what you want. It seems to me you want to put in the *value* of an enum in there, since the field is named `enumValue`. So you should pass in `StatusEnum.Okay`, or something like that, not a type.

You already have the type from the type parameter, so if it is to do about the type, you don't need to pass in that parameter at all.

Comment: I have updated my post with an example of passing the "type" working. I just wanted to know if it is possible using TEnum generics instead

Comment: The non generic way yes. Using TEnum in combination with the Where clause No. That is all in my original question

Comment: But what is the purpose of the `where`? The `TEnum` must be a `struct`, etc.? While you pass in a `Type`?

Comment: See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755630/cannot-convert-type-tenum-to-int